# how to manage multiple Python distributions on one device

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I have a macbook pro, and I have Python 2.7,3.3 and 3.4 and Anaconda 2.7 installed, and I am having a hard time managing all these multiple Python distributions. These are the problems I am facing :

- pip install installs for anaconda 2.7 by default, how do I make it install for PYthon 2.7 ?
- how do I make pip3 install work for different Python distributions? i.e is there some way I can use something like pip3 install -v 3.3.6 or something similar.

how do I find a workaround for these problems. I wish to know the answer in both the basic sense (how Python and Anaconda work, and what happens when I use pip install, and how do I use these to solve my problem), and also in the practical sense (is there some simple way to manage this problem).

Comment: Seems like the problem that [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) was created to fix. . .

Comment: Use the versioned form of `pip`, e.g. `pip2.7`, `pip3.3` and `pip3.4`. Given PY2.7 and Anaconda share the same python version you will need to check your path try `which -a pip2.7` from the terminal and explicitly call the right deployment of `pip`. But I echo @mgilson, create a `virtualenv`, then when you activate it `pip` will be in that virtualenv and packages will be installed locally to the virtualenv.

Comment: when you type "pip" then windows searches through its "path" variable. pip or the python's installation folder gets added to this path variable after installation. Which installation folder gets accessed can easily be modified over here.

Answer (score 0):

To install packages for specific python versions, it is easiest to run python with the -m flag. The -m flag will run the specified module as a script. Calling `python -m pip install _package_` will run pip for whatever python you specify.

Examples:

```
python -m pip install _package_
python3 -m pip install _package_
python2.7 -m pip install _package_
python3.7 -m pip install _package_
```